# Java Stream with ForEach iteration issue

Tags: java, foreach, java-8, java-stream

I have two type of implementations for processing. Not sure why stream forEach loop complains that variable 'i' must be final. But if final, then how to address issue with logic of computing 'i'?

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String str = "123456789";
    int i = 0;
    //Non Stream
    for (char c : str.toCharArray()) {
        if (c >= 48 && c <= 57) {
            i = i * 10 + (c - 48);
        }
    }
    System.out.println(i);
     i = 0;
    // WHY compiler fails for variable 'i' here? 
    str.chars().forEach((c) -> {
        if (c >= 48 && c <= 57) {
            i = i * 10 + (c - 48);
        }
    });
    System.out.println(i);
}
```

Comment: While the meaning of the number constants is derivable from context, there is no reason to use `48` and `57` instead of `'0'` and `'9'`…

Comment: good point about character ascii value replacement.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can replace the `forEach` with a [reduction](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/streams/reduction.html). For example:

```
int i = str.chars()
           .filter( c -> c >= 48 && c <= 57 )
           .reduce( 0, (a, b) -> a * 10 + (b - 48) );
```

Here, `0` is the initial value and the lambda expression calculates the new value. `a` is the result of the latest calculation, and `b` is the next element in the stream. Effectively, rather than using a local variable to track (accumulate) the latest calculation, the accumulator is maintained within the reducer.